# Cannot find an executable for a non root user over ssh

Tags: ssh, qnx

Note: i am reposting the question as i am not able to reply or comment.

I am creating a non-root user to execute an object file alone (without root access). My intention is to have the user run a file which is residing at `/atlas/Bin`. So i set `/etc/passwd` as `user:x:0:0:test:/:/atlas/Bin/object`. But when I open a new shell(through teraterm) over SSH to login to the user, I get an error as it cannot find the object.

I have made the changes to `/etc/profile` to set the PATH to include `/atlas/Bin` to help find the object. Not sure what I am missing here. If I instead login with the root user over SSH, I can execute this object without an issue.

I am providing the `/etc` values I use for the build file below.

## /etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/:/bin/sh
....
user:x:0:0:test:/:/atlas/Bin/object
sshd:x:15:6:sshd:/var/chroot/sshd:/bin/sh
```

## /etc/group

```
root:x:0:root
...
sshd:x:6:user
```

## /etc/profile

```
PATH=/atlas/Bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/dll/
alias ll="ls -l"
```

## /etc/ssh/ssh_config

```
Host *
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

## /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Protocol 2
LoginGraceTime 600
LogLevel    DEBUG3
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

Comment: By running the binary that way, you're missing out on the normal user shell startup sequence, some of which may matter here. What happens if you give the user a normal login shell but put the `/atlas/Bin/object` executable call in at the end of the user's `.profile` or `.bash_profile`? Also, are you sure it's `Bin` and not `bin`? I don't know if QNX's filesystem is case-sensitive, but if it is, that difference will matter.

Comment: My intention is to not provide the user with root access. This particular user should login only to run this binary! I am sure it is Bin.

Comment: So make the command `exec /atlas/Bin/object`, so that the user is logged out as soon as that program exits.

Comment: As for providing the user root access, you might want to re-think giving the user ID 0. That not only gives this "atlas" program root access, it means any security vulnerability in that program becomes a remote root access vulnerability. But that is a separate question, better taken up elsewhere.

Comment: Cross-posted questions are usually closed. I'd advise deleting the [so] version because it's not on-topic for that site (and is likely to be closed for that reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the excutable as shell for the user, then you may need to add the program to `/etc/shells`.

You may want to use a restricted shell for the user with a profile that runs your script and exits.

You may be able to use `/bin/false` as the shell and a command specified in the authorized_keys file for the key being used to access the server. If `/bin/false` doesn't work try a restricted shell such as `/usr/bin/rbash`.